# Spring Boot: Unable to look up data source

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm

I'm running an application framework (jbpm) on Spring Boot which requires looking up a Datasource.
I'm facing the following error:

```java
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to look up data source: java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS - Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
        at org.jbpm.process.workitem.executesql.ExecuteSqlWorkItemHandler.<init>(ExecuteSqlWorkItemHandler.java:83) ~[execute-sql-workitem-7.52.0.Final.jar:7.52.0.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

I have got the following properties in application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=sa
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    
    #hibernate configuration
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I have also added in my configuration class the following:

```java
    @Bean
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
            JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
            bean.setJndiName("java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS");
            bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
            bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }
```

I have checked the code of the jbpm handler:
https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items/blob/main/execute-sql-workitem/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/executesql/ExecuteSqlWorkItemHandler.java#L79
I see this is the code which does the lookup:

```java
    this.ds = InitialContext.doLookup(dataSourceName);
```

What am I missing in my code/configuration?
Thanks

Edit: here's the core section of pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <version.org.kie>7.52.0.Final</version.org.kie>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <narayana.version>5.9.0.Final</narayana.version>
    <fabric8.version>3.5.40</fabric8.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>execute-sql-workitem</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you share the pom.xml

Comment: I'm confused. I believe you are mixing things up or missing some information. Do you want to configure your datasource with JNDI or through Spring boot? I guess you could remove your Datasource @Bean and it would work fine

Comment: Basically, it's a Java class that runs on Spring Boot and does a lookup of a Datasource. I have initially tried with "spring.datasource.jndi-name" but that is needed if I deploy the Spring Boot application on an Application Server which is not the case. If I remove the @Bean definition I won't be able to look up the Datasource either.